# Is there way to know if user is currently playing my application

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to know if a user is currently logged into my app and playing it. Besides creating my own JS code that sends a heartbeat occasionally, is there something like this that already exists in the FB JS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

`No`. Nothing such exists in the FB JS SDK...